# node command fails when run from npm-run-script

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm getting some strange behaviour when running a node script through `package.json` yet it runs fine from the terminal.

If I run either of the following from the bash shell they work.

```
node --harmony-async-await index.js
node --harmony-async-await jasmine.js
```

But if I add the following to my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node --harmony-async-await index.js",
  "test": "node --harmony-async-await jasmine.js"
}
```

The start script runs fine but I get errors when I run the test script, I'm running node v7.3.0. Here is the output of `npm-debug.log`:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/marktyers/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/marktyers/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'test' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v7.3.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ]
5 info lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~pretest: bookshop@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~pretest: no script for pretest, continuing
7 info lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~test: bookshop@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~test: PATH: /Users/marktyers/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/marktyers/Documents/bookshop/node_modules/.bin:/Users/marktyers/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.0/bin:/Users/marktyers/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/texbin
10 verbose lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~test: CWD: /Users/marktyers/Documents/bookshop
11 silly lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~test: Args: [ '-c', 'node --harmony-async-await jasmine.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle bookshop@1.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
14 verbose stack Error: bookshop@1.0.0 test: `node --harmony-async-await jasmine.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/marktyers/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/marktyers/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid bookshop@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/marktyers/Documents/bookshop
17 error Darwin 16.3.0
18 error argv "/Users/marktyers/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.0/bin/node" "/Users/marktyers/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.0/bin/npm" "run" "test"
19 error node v7.3.0
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error bookshop@1.0.0 test: `node --harmony-async-await jasmine.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the bookshop@1.0.0 test script 'node --harmony-async-await jasmine.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bookshop package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node --harmony-async-await jasmine.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs bookshop
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls bookshop
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I'm struggling to understand why the command produces different results.

Comment: Have you tried updating your packages with `npm update`?. Another interesting thing is that I've did a bit of research on that `bookshop` package, and current version is 0.0.3 https://github.com/chenglou/bookshop/blob/master/package.json, and the debug is displaying 1.0.0... that's a bit suspicious.

Comment: deleted all packages and reinstalled when I updated node. bookshop package is my own app which is set to version `1.0.0`, where are you seeing the `0.0.3` version?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshop  from this, I thought is was a public package

Comment: David, I can see the source of confusion there...